# What happens when I tap the map?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I tap the map (by map I mean the map the character walks on - the ground), it glows a bit.

[image: Tap animation]

What happens when I click the map? Is it just an visual effect or does it cause anything else?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The visual effect is what we refer to in the industry as "feedback". It is a way of confirming input, where other elements in play may not.

If you tap on an object such as a pokémon or a pokéstop, and you see that effect, it means that the game has not registered your input on an object. Instead, it has interpreted your tap as being on vacant ground.

Apart from that, the effect has no other function.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, there *is* an effect: in case you have only one hand available, you can zoom by tapping the map and then dragging downwards from the blue circle that appears.

But that is its only function.

Comment: It's _downwards_ actually.

Comment: Good catch, tested it to confirm, and answer's been updated.

Comment: Well, its down to zoom in, up to zoom out.

Answer (score -3):

I personally think it helps you find hidden pokies. I haven't tested it out enough to say for sure, but when green grass rustles near me, I tapped around it (it was right outside my circle) and a Nidorian appeared down the stream a bit, pretty far outside my circle. The game froze when I caught him, and when I restarted it he grass was back, I tapped in the same spot, and he appeared again.
I tried it down the street, and 2 more appeared (but that could have been a coincidence of some randomly appearing).
I'm going to keep trying I case I'm on to something.